# Node passing parameters through Q service promise

Tags: node.js, q

I have a middleware setup in node to perform a task and call next upon success or failure. The task is called after an initial promise block runs. It is called in the .then function:

```
var Q  = require('q');

var dataPromise = getCustomerId();

dataPromise  
   .then(function(data) {
         getGUID(req, res, next);
      }, function(error) {
         console.log('Failure...', error);
    });  

};
```

The server hangs though because the (req,res,next) parameters are all undefined when in the context of the .then function.

Here is getCustomerId function:

```
var getCustomerId = function() {

var getCustomerIdOptions = {
  options...
};

var deferred = Q.defer();
request(getCustomerIdOptions, function(err,resp,body){
  if(err){
    deferred.reject(err);
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }else{
    deferred.resolve(body);
  }

});
return deferred.promise;
};
```

What would be the correct way to pass these parameters to the function called in the .then block?

EDIT:
The (req,res,next) parameters are from the outer function and are accessible when getGUID(req,res,next) is called outside of the .then() block.

```
 var assureGUID = function(req, res, next) {
   if(app.locals.guid){ 
    next();
   return;
 }

 var dataPromise = getCustomerId();

 dataPromise  
  .then(function(data) {
      getGUID(req, res, next)
  }, function(error) {
     console.log('Failure...', error);
  }).;
};
```

Comment: Could you show us where those arguments are suppose to come from? You are most likely missing the entire wrapping function which is registered in the middleware framework that is suppose to provide them.

Comment: I've added my outer function which has the parameters available.

Comment: yes it is an express app

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but you can call your promise function  inside a express common  middleware function like the next sample.

```
var express = require('express');
var $q = require('q');
var request = require('request');


var app = express();

// Middleware 1
app.use( function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('i\'m the first middleware');

  getCustomerId().then( function(body) {
    console.log('response body', body);
    return next();
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('Error on middlware 1: ', err);
  });

});


// Middleware 2
app.use( function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('i\'m the second middleware');
  return next();
});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hi world');
});


app.listen(3000);


// Your custom function definition
function getCustomerId() {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  request('http://someurltogetjsondata/user/id',  function(err, resp, body) {
    if(err) return deferred.reject(err);
    deferred.resolve(body);
  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

I hope this helps a little, good luck.